# Form action not working with special characters (&)

Tags: php, html, forms, action

I have a reservation form and the form action should be: 
https://reservations.posthotel.com/smsworld/wc.dll?smsworld~availbox~
But it's not working. When I submit the form, everything from ? is just ignored.

As a solution, I named the first field as

> name="smsworld~availbox~&RAD"

It's ALMOST working, the only problem now is that when I submit my form, the "&" is being switched by %26.

The URL that I should get is:

https://reservations.posthotel.com/smsworld/wc.dll?smsworld~availbox~&RAD=10%2F15%2F2014&RDD=10%2F21%2F2014&nights=3&RCA=2

But instead, I'm getting:
https://reservations.posthotel.com/smsworld/wc.dll?smsworld~availbox~%26RAD=10%2F15%2F2014&RDD=10%2F21%2F2014&nights=6&RCA=2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all the replies, but I've found a solution for this using a few lines of javascript.

> $('.submit-btn').on('click', function(e) {
>
> ```
>   var checkinDate = $('#checkAvailDate').val(),
>       guests = parseInt($'#checkAvailAdults').val()) + parseInt($('#checkAvailChildren').val());
>
>   var formAction = 'https://reservations.posthotel.com/smsworld/wc.dll?smsworld~availbox~&RAD=10%2F15%2F2014&nights=6&RCA=' + guests;
>
>   var win = window.open(formAction, '_blank');
>   win.focus();
>   e.preventDefault();
> ```
>
> });

I'm not done with formatting all the fields yet, but even then, thank you very much for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using GET or POST (the method attribute on the form) ? If GET, the URL in the action cannot contain query-string parameters. Try using POST instead.

I just made a fiddle for you which has two forms.  One using GET (does not work) and the other using POST (Seems to work):

```
<form action="https://reservations.posthotel.com/smsworld/wc.dll?smsworld~availbox~" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit GET" />
</form>


<form action="https://reservations.posthotel.com/smsworld/wc.dll?smsworld~availbox~" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit POST" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n80e6Lzv/

Answer (score 1):

What you're observing is URL encoding.  Certain characters in URL's are reserved characters, such that you cannot make parts of the URL that contain that character, or else the URL will get misinterpreted.  Ampersand is one of those characters.

Consider what a URL with a query string looks like:

http://test.com?name1=value1&name2=value2

As you're probably already aware, the query string variables are separated by an ampersand.  URL encoding substitutes a group of characters for a reserved character, to prevent misinterpretations of the URL.

In other words, the URL you're asking for is impossible.  Your GET data would be interpreted as:

```
$_GET = array(
     'smsworld~availbox~' => '',
     'RAD' => '10/15/2014',  //An additional index created by the unencoded ampersand
     //etc...
);
```

If that extra `RAD` index was your actual intent, that is not possible this way. You should be making use of hidden fields to add `RAD` as an additional query string variable instead.  One form field for each query string variable only.